# Absolute Positioning Varies Between Browsers when Using Pseudo-Elements

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element

I am modifying a download link to display two icons above it (using pseudo-elements and an icon font). These icons need to be layered.

To do that, I've given the link a `position: relative` and the second icon (which I'm positioning over top of the first) gets a `position: absolute`. Then I just adjusted the `top` and `left` values until it sat where I wanted.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju3owvgh/)**

```css
@import url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

body {
    /* just to make sure everything fits on screen */
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.download {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.download::before {
    display: block;
    content:'\f1c1';
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 42pt;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.download::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content:'\f019';
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 28pt;
    top: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="download">Download PDF</a>
```

In Chrome, it works perfectly. The "download" icon sits right on top of the bottom-right of the "document" icon. In firefox, however, the "download" icon is hovering way above the "document" icon. I suspect this is a result of the pseudo-element not technically being a DOM child of the `a.download` element, although [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fv9Ldowz/) (which doesn't use pseudo-elements) has the same positioning problem.

How do the browsers' implementations of `position: absolute` in conjunction with pseudo-elements differ, and how can I work around this?

Comment: although [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fv9Ldowz/) which doesn't use pseudo-elements still has the same positioning problem.

Comment: To me Chrome looks broken here, but as to why i don't have much of an idea at the moment but looking forward to answers as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i've got it.

The `<a>` tag is collapsing on Chrome but on Firefox it's being given a box. It seems the best bet would be to give the `<a>` tag some `padding-top` to push the text down then also absolutely position the acrobat icon as well. I'm not quite sure how to make it not collapse on Chrome

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5jn9yw7s/

```css
@import url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

body {
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.download {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.download::before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content:'\f1c1';
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 42pt;
    top: -52pt;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -21pt;
}

.download::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content:'\f019';
    font-family:'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 28pt;
    top: -32pt;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="download">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: you were right! positioning the document icon with absolute positioning as well worked. perhaps you'd like to update your answer with [this working code](http://jsfiddle.net/5jn9yw7s/)?

Comment: Sure thing! I just played around inline, should probably get into the habit of actually editing the fiddles

Answer (score 0):

In firefox the pseudo elements' absolute positioning ignored and treated as two relative elements. You can set firefox specific fix for this by adding this to your css:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .download::after {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top:58px
   }
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svxpwhg7/)

Play with margins for better result.

Comment: thank you, but i'd rather find one solution that works consistently across all/most browsers rather than a fix that's targeted at a single browser but still might leave other untested browsers broken.